# Is there any way to listen to eventbus from an ember-modal dialog?

Tags: ember.js, modal-dialog, event-bus

The scenario is to listen to an eventbus notification when the ember modal is open, refresh the route page while closing the modal, as i am not able to subscribe to the event from ember modal, unable to do the conditional refresh.

Comment: We need more information about your context. What’s the event bus implementation? How does one subscribe to events? A `Service` may be of use here.

Comment: code example of modal, code of subscription may help. give more details please